# Regular expression to restrict to 100 characters without considering space and dot

Tags: regex

Is there a way to limit the length of characters to 100 without taking into consideration blank spaces and dots using regular expression?

I have an expression `^\s*([^\s]\s*){0,100}$` which exempts space only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your regex slightly to make it work:

```
^[\s.]*([^\s.][\s.]*){0,100}$
```

I assume that you want to reject any message that is longer than 100 characters, since you included `$` in your question.

Comment: Thank you @nhahtdh for the answer. It's working fine :) Yes, my requirement is minimum 5 characters and a max of 100; so {5,100}$ will do right...

Answer (score 0):

*Using regex* `^([\s.]*([^\s.][\s.]*){0,100})` *you will get your match for first up to 100 characters (excl. spaces and dots).*

*If you want to validate input if is up to 100 characters (excl. spaces and dots), then do no use grouping `( ... )` and add `$` at the end:* `^[\s.]*([^\s.][\s.]*){0,100}$`*.*